# Resolve .jsx extensions on imports in node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I have a CRA project in which I've added SSR. 
It's supper dummy, it has this structure:

```
|- App.js
|- Header
  |- Header.jsx
  |- Header.scss
```

The App just contains the Header, which is imported without specifying the extension.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header/Header';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

With `npm start` all runs successfully. If I compile the code and run it with node instead, it breaks with this error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

**There seem to be a problem when resolving imports without an extension**. It finds the .scss file instead of the .jsx. Specifying the extension on import or removing conlicting files (i.e. Header.scss) solves the issue.
However, I would like to keep using imports without extension, as I normally do in CRA.

I don't know how to specify this on [my settings](https://github.com/dnaranjo89/resolve_extensions_ssr/blob/master/server/index.js).

I've just pushed this simple example so you can run it yourself: https://github.com/dnaranjo89/resolve_extensions_ssr

Comment: Wouldn't it be simplet to have files named `Header/index.jsx` and `Header/styles.scss`?

Comment: In angular, files are named `<component-name>.component.ts`, `<component-name>.styles.css` and `<component-name>.template.html`. It seems like a good practice to have different file names, excluding the extension

Comment: Hi @NinoFiliu, using `index.jsx` looks indeed like a good option if I don't get it to work with the current file structure. My actual project is quite bigger and I would like to avoid renaming so many files if possible

Comment: Ok, seems fair then - it wasn't precised in your question, I couldn't know